# How to compute realized volatility

Tags: feature-engineering, finance, volatility

I am provided with a dataset consisting of an open book and a trade book

The open book data has the following columns:

1. Bid price/size 1
2. Bid price/size 2
3. Ask price/size 1
4. Ask price/size 2
5. time id
6. seconds in bucket

The trade book data has the following columns:

1. time id
2. seconds in bucket
3. price
4. size
5. order count

We have to estimate the realized volatility using this dataset. It is quite clear that for doing this, I have to construct new features using the data already given.

***My question is 2 fold;***
***1. Which of the given columns is the most related with realized volatility?***
***2. How could I make new features using the given ones?***

Answer (score 0):

I would begin with

- Realized Volatility: A Review by Michael McAleer & Marcelo C. Medeiros
- Realised Kernels in Practice: Trades and Quotes by Barndorff-Nielsen et al

Both are available online.